# PHP web page middle div content loading twice

Tags: php, jquery, html

My website is in bespoke CMS, and I have a webpage titled as edit profile and for some reason the content of the page in the middle div is loading twice, the tabs on the left hand side always appear twice whereas the right hand side duplication disappears after clicking on any one of the tabs on the left hand side. But the content on both sides always loads twice on a refresh.

the link to my page is:
http://newtongrads.com/edit-profile

I would be happy if someone could help me, I've been trying to work out a solution and its been a long time since I'm stuck in it

Comment: You have to log in to see that page. Can you do something about that or rather post screenshots/code snippets? I don' want to sign up on your site.

Comment: post your code else we can't help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok I am posting my Code

Comment: Its not letting me post my code in ... :/

Comment: I can provide a dummy login ID 
username: pm1test1grad2@newtongrads.com

Comment: password: pm1test1grad2